# Bug in VCL styles - Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, styles

I am using XE5 and VCL styles. I see there is a bug in VCL styles when you use maximized windows. Here is the DFM file

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 326
  Top = 150
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 636
  ClientWidth = 1289
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  WindowState = wsMaximized
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
end
```

From Project Options just enable "Aqua Light Slate" and set it as Default Style. Compile and run. Remember WindowState is wsMaximized. You can see that Window's height is more than desktop's working area.

PS: I am using Windows 8.1

Does anyone else face the same problem? Are there any fix for this bug?

Thanks

Comment: I've been experiencing similar issues with multiple monitors, where after maximizing, it leaks into the next screen like 5 pixels. But then again, same happens with Windows default drawing too.

Comment: See [QC 110953 Maximized window with VCL Styles enabled expands to second monitor](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=110953). Seems to be resolved in XE8.

Comment: I am not sure if my problem is the same. I am using single monitor. All I see is borders over taskbar.

Comment: I use XE7 and have used XE2, but have never used XE5. In XE7 it works for me using Windows 7.

Comment: Do you have any custom taskbar / start menu modification software installed?

Comment: @Jerry Your first comment isn't right. Windows doesn't leak maximised window borders. VCL styles may well do.

Comment: @David I've had plenty problems with various different software, including that made by Microsoft themselves, where maximized windows leak a few pixels over into the next monitor.

Comment: @Jerry Please provide a repro to back up your original comment then

Comment: Well this is a BUG and why do i need to buy a new version to fix the BUG? They have to fix it.